# VBA to copy paste values into last row with formulas in other columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not really all too familiar with VBA and am learning it as I need things to be automated. I actually figured out an alternative by going through a table instead, but I'm curious to know how I might resolve this in the future.

So, I am taking data and pasting it into col C in a table and appending data to the last row. Other columns in the table are driven by the data in this column and have a formula in them that returns nothing/stays blank if C is blank. Every month, I go to clear column C for the next month's data and have no issues initially copying the first set of data. The problem comes when I need to add dataset 2 to column C. Despite referencing column C as the column I want to look at for the last row, it keeps pasting the data starting at the last row before the prior month's data was deleted (and where the formulas have auto-populated through the table's expansion). There is a huge gap and it's almost like it's looking at the formulas in the other columns.

```
Sub xyz()

Dim wrkst1 As Worksheet
Dim wrkst2 As Worksheet
Dim LRst As Long
Dim Rng As Range

Dim LR1 As Long
Dim LR2 As Long

Set wrkst1 = Sheets("1")
Set wrkst2 = Sheets("2")

LR1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

'clearing last month's data
    wrkst1.Range("C5:C" & LR1).ClearContents

'Setting up the LR of wkst 1
With wrkst1.Range("C11")
    LR3 = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
End With

Set Rng = wrkst1.Range("C11:C" & LRst)

    LR3 = Rng.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("C11"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row


'Identify the last row of origin sheet data
    LR2 = wrkst2.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    
'Copy and paste data set 1
    wrkst2.Range("L15:L" & LR2 - 1).Copy
        wrkst1.Range("C12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        
'Appending data set 2
    wrkst2.Range("M15:M" & LR2 - 1).Copy
        wrkst1.Range("C" & LR3 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This is the following I used to replace the former LR3.

```
Dim tbl As ListObject


Set tbl = wrkst1.ListObjects("Table1")

With tbl.ListColumns(3).Range
    LR3 = .Find(What:="*", _
                After:=.Cells(1), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
End With
```

Comment: It looks like the `With` statement contains a complicated way to write `LRst 
= wrkst1.Range("C11").Row`, i.e. `LRst` is always `11`, `Rng .Address` is always `C11`, `LR3` is always `11`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Oh, that LRst is actually supposed to be LR3, but I see what you're saying. I'll have a go with that during the next cycle.